# C++ Comparison between template parameters seems to be ignored

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, template-meta-programming

```
// III
template <
    size_t N_CURRENT,
    size_t N_END,
    size_t N_BEGIN = N_CURRENT,
    char ... Cr,
    size_t SUBSTRING_LENGTH = N_END - N_BEGIN
>
constexpr static_string substr() const noexcept {
    static_assert(N_END >= N_CURRENT, "static_string::substr(): N_END 
must be more than or equal to N_CURRENT!");

return N_CURRENT == N_END
    ? static_string(SUBSTRING_LENGTH, Cr...)
    : substr<N_CURRENT+1, N_END, N_BEGIN, Cr..., ' '>(); //causes a lot of recursion errors...
    // note the ' ' in substr<N_CURRENT+1, B_END, B_BEGIN, Cr..., ' '> has been added for testing purposes.
}
```

I'm sorry the title is a bit vague: I do not know exactly what the problem is.
However:
The expression N_CURRENT == N_END seems to be ignored and the latter return value gets used. Even if I change N_CURRENT == N_END to true, the latter is still being used. The errors only show up when I actually call the function, for example

```
static_string str = str1.substr<4, 7>();
```

Could anyone explain to me why this is happening and help me to find a solution for this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post the code of `static_string`?

Comment: It doesn't matter if `N_CURRENT == N_END` is true or false, both possible results need to be well formed. While the second result won't be evaluated at run time if the condition is `true`, the expression itself will still be looked at to at least determine it's type. When `N_CURRENT == N_END`, you will still need to specialize `substr()` for `<N_CURRENT+1, N_END, N_BEGIN, Cr..., ' '>` which causes an infinite recursion even if you can't possibly call it or use it's result.

Comment: This is not even a valid template.  A variadic parameter must be the last parameter in the template. `size_t SUBSTRING_LENGTH = N_END - N_BEGIN` cannot follow after `char ... Cr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your problems is simple, the ternary operator is evaluated too late:

```
N_CURRENT == N_END
    ? static_string(SUBSTRING_LENGTH, Cr...)
    : substr<N_CURRENT+1, N_END, N_BEGIN, Cr..., ' '>()
```

This means that the condition is checked only after the following is getting instantiated:

```
substr<N_CURRENT+1, N_END, N_BEGIN, Cr..., ' '>
```

The ternary operator avoids execution of the wrong path, but it does not avoid compilation.
In order to make it work you should use the following C++17 feature:

```
if constexpr(N_CURRENT == N_END)
  return static_string(SUBSTRING_LENGTH, Cr...);
else
  return substr<N_CURRENT+1, N_END, N_BEGIN, Cr..., ' '>()
```

This way, the else part is only partially parsed, without instantiating `substr<>()`

If your compiler does not support `if constexpr` of c++17, then you have to write different functions for the different cases, and enable/disable them with `std::enable_if`. (Since I don't really know how the rest of the code works, I am only guessing how your code should look like. Especially, I don't know what Cr... is, so most likely I am doing it wrong. I suggest that you take the ideas and work with them.)
Here is the way `std::enable_if` should work on your code:

```
template <int N_CURRENT,
          int N_END, int N_BEGIN,
          int SUBSTRING_LENGTH,
          class ...Params, 
          class = typename std::enable_if<N_CURRENT == N_END>::type >
constexpr auto do_substr(Params ...Cr)
{
   return static_string(SUBSTRING_LENGTH, Cr...);
}
```

and
    template ::type >
    constexpr auto do_substr(Params ...Cr)
    {
        return substr()
    }

And call it instead of the ternary operator:

```
return do_substr<N_CURRENT, N_END, N_BEGIN, Params...>(Cr...);
```

Since I don't know what your code is doing, I have avoided perfect forwarding of the parameter pack, but feel free to use

```
do_substr(Params && ...Cr)
```

and

```
std::forward<Params>(Cr)...
```